# Путь к сокровищу стал на два часа короче

Tags: перевод, предлоги

From the Alchemist by Paulo Coelho,

> Путь к сокровищу стал на два часа короче.

If I understand this sentence correctly, it means

> The path to the treasure stood 2 hours closer.

But why is **на** used here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Стал* is the past tense of *стать*, no longer related in modern Russian to any of *стоять*'s prefixed perfective pairs. It's "the path to the treasure *became* shorter by two hours".

*На* is always used when specifying the amount with comparatives; an exception is *раз* ("times") which uses *в*, as in **в два раза быстрее** "twice as fast". This "*в* for multiplication" is also reflected in adverbialised compounds such as *вдвое* or *втрое*. Other than that, even fractions, percentages and logarithmics use *на*: **на две третьих меньше** "less by two thirds", **на порядок дороже** "more expensive by an order of magnitude".